# Will there be a new ArcGIS API for Silverlight that will be updated for ArcGIS 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, arcgis-10.4, maintenance

Will there be a new ArcGIS API for Silverlight that will be 100% compatible with ArcGIS Server 10.4 (*I know a lot of 3.3 API works, but I also know that older APIS never completely work and have to be adjusted*).

I also know that Esri is retiring 3.x on 2016-06-01, I'm thinking there's a good chance that there will be no new release. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I had the [**Deprecated Features for ArcGIS 10.3.1 and 10.4 Releases**](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/W34229_DEPRECATION_PLAN_FOR_ARCGIS_10_4_and_10_3_1__082015.pdf) open in my browser and didn't read down all the way.  It's right in there:

> [Added January 24, 2015] ArcGIS API 3.3 for Silverlight and ArcGIS
>   Viewer 3.3 for Silverlight will be the final releases.